# neo4j 2.0 findNodesByLabelAndProperty not working

Tags: neo4j

I'm currently trying the Neo4j 2.0.0 M3 and see some strange behaviour. **In my unit tests, everything works as expected** (using an `newImpermanentDatabase`) but in the real thing, I **do not get results** from the `graphDatabaseService.findNodesByLabelAndProperty`.

Here is the code in question:

```
ResourceIterator<Node> iterator = graphDB
            .findNodesByLabelAndProperty(Labels.User, "EMAIL_ADDRESS", emailAddress)
            .iterator();
try {
    if (iterator.hasNext()) { // => returns false**
        return iterator.next();
    }
} finally {
    iterator.close();
}
return null;
```

This returns no results. However, when running the following code, I see my node is there (The MATCH!!!!!!!!! is printed) and I also have an index setup via the schema (although that if I read the API, this seems not necessary but is important for performance):

```
ResourceIterator<Node> iterator1 = GlobalGraphOperations.at(graphDB).getAllNodesWithLabel(Labels.User).iterator();
    while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
        Node result = iterator1.next();
        UserDao.printoutNode(emailAddress, result);
    }
```

And UserDao.printoutNode

```
public static void printoutNode(String emailAddress, Node next) {
    System.out.print(next);
    ResourceIterator<Label> iterator1 = next.getLabels().iterator();
    System.out.print("(");
    while (iterator1.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(iterator1.next().name());
    }

    System.out.print("): ");
    for(String key : next.getPropertyKeys()) {
        System.out.print(key + ": " + next.getProperty(key).toString() + "; ");
        if(emailAddress.equals( next.getProperty(key).toString())) {
            System.out.print("MATCH!!!!!!!!!");
        }
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

I already debugged through the code and what I already found out is that I pass via the `InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.map2Nodes` to a `DelegatingIndexProxy.getDelegate` and end up in `IndexReader.Empty` class which returns the `IteratorUtil.EMPTY_ITERATOR` thus getting `false` for `iterator.hasNext()`

Any idea's what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Found it: I only included neo4j-kernel:2.0.0-M03 in the classpath. The moment I added neo4j-cypher:2.0.0-M03 all was working well.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO.  If you've found your own solution, you are encouraged to write it as an answer and mark it as selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it:

I only included `neo4j-kernel:2.0.0-M03` in the classpath. The moment I added `neo4j-cypher:2.0.0-M03` all was working well.

Hope this answer helps save some time for other users.

@Neo4j: would be nice if an exception would be thrown instead of just returning nothing.

@Ricardo: I wanted to but I was not allowed yet as my reputation wasn't good enough as a new SO user.